# System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment

Does anyone know why i get:

> System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001  Stack Trace:
>   Class.CreateInvoice.: line 36, column 1
>   Class.CreateInvoiceTestClass.testData: line 57, column 1

```
    @isTest(SeeAllData=true) 
public class CreateInvoiceTestClass{

    // Creating Test Data
   @isTest public static void testData(){

        Account account = new Account(Name = 'TestAccount1');  
        insert account;

        List<Training__c> trainingList = new List<Training__c>();
        for(integer counter=0;counter<20;counter++){

            Training__c trainingRecord = new Training__c();
            trainingRecord.name = 'TestRecord'+counter;
            trainingRecord.Startdatum__c = System.today().addDays(+2);
            trainingRecord.factuur_bedrijf__c = account.Id;
            trainingList.add(trainingRecord);
        }
        insert trainingList;

         List<Facturatie__c> facturatieList = new List<Facturatie__c>();
        for(integer counter=0;counter<20;counter++){

            Facturatie__c facturatieRecord = new Facturatie__c();
            facturatieRecord.name = 'TestRecord'+counter;
            facturatieRecord.Factuur_Bedrag__c = 1000;
            facturatieRecord.Training__c = trainingList[counter].Id;
            facturatieList.add(facturatieRecord);
        }

       for(integer counter=0;counter<20;counter++){

            Facturatie__c facturatieRecord = new Facturatie__c();
            facturatieRecord.name = 'TestRecord2'+counter;
            facturatieRecord.Factuur_Bedrag__c = 1000;
            facturatieRecord.Training__c = trainingList[counter].Id;
            facturatieList.add(facturatieRecord);
        }

       insert facturatieList;


        List<Cursist__c> cursistList = new List<Cursist__c>();
        for(integer counter=0;counter<20;counter++){

            Cursist__c cursistRecord = new Cursist__c();           
            cursistRecord.Training__c = trainingList[counter].Id;
            cursistRecord.Prijs_training__c = 10;
            cursistRecord.korting__c = 10;
            cursistRecord.CreatedDate = System.today();
            cursistList.add(cursistRecord);
        }
        insert cursistList;

       system.debug(facturatieList[0].Account__c);
       Test.StartTEst();
       CreateInvoice createInv = new CreateInvoice();
       Test.stopTest();

       System.assertEquals(facturatieList[0].Account__c,null);

    }

}
```

Class being tested

```
public class CreateInvoice{

    public CreateInvoice(){

        List<Training__c> trainingList = new List<Training__c>();
        List<Facturatie__c> facturatieList = new List<Facturatie__c>();

        try {
        trainingList = [SELECT id , NAME, Startdatum__c,factuur_bedrijf__c,
                          (SELECT Cursist_Prijs__c, Training__c, Cursist__c,CreatedDate,Prijs_training__c,
                           korting__c,Id 
                           FROM Trainingen_Volgen__r ) 
                       FROM  Training__c 
                       WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT  Training__c FROM Facturatie__c)];
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred' + e.getMessage() +
                         'At line number :' + e.getLineNumber() + 'Error' +
                         e.getStackTraceString());
        }              
        if(!trainingList.IsEmpty()){

            for(Training__c trainingRecord : trainingList){

                if(!trainingRecord.Trainingen_Volgen__r.IsEmpty()){

                    for(Cursist__c cursistRecord : trainingRecord.Trainingen_Volgen__r){

                        Facturatie__c facturatieRecord = checkDate(cursistRecord,trainingRecord);
                        facturatieList.add(facturatieRecord);
                    }
                }   
            }

            if(!facturatieList.IsEmpty()){  
               try {
                   insert facturatieList;
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.debug('The following exception has occurred' + e.getMessage() +
                                 'At line number :' + e.getLineNumber() + 'Error' +
                                 e.getStackTraceString());
                }   

            }
        }   
    }

    public Facturatie__c checkDate(Cursist__c cursistRecord,Training__c trainingRecord){

        if(cursistRecord != null && trainingRecord != null){
            Date todaysDate = system.today();

            if( todaysDate.addDays(-21) >= trainingRecord.Startdatum__c 
                && todaysDate >= cursistRecord.CreatedDate 
                && todaysDate.addDays(-1) >= trainingRecord.Startdatum__c){

                Facturatie__c facturatieRecord = new Facturatie__c();

                facturatieRecord.Training__c = trainingRecord.Id;   
                facturatieRecord.Factuur_Datum__c = todaysDate;  
                facturatieRecord.Verval_datum__c = todaysDate.addDays(30);

                if(cursistRecord.Prijs_training__c != null &&  cursistRecord.korting__c != null){
                    facturatieRecord.Factuur_Bedrag__c = cursistRecord.Prijs_training__c - cursistRecord.korting__c;
                }else if(cursistRecord.Prijs_training__c != null && cursistRecord.korting__c == null){
                    facturatieRecord.Factuur_Bedrag__c = cursistRecord.Prijs_training__c;
                }else if(cursistRecord.Prijs_training__c == null && cursistRecord.korting__c != null){
                    facturatieRecord.Factuur_Bedrag__c = cursistRecord.korting__c ;
                }

                facturatieRecord.Korting__c =  cursistRecord.korting__c;
                facturatieRecord.cursist_prijs__c= cursistRecord.Cursist_Prijs__c ;
                facturatieRecord.Contactpersoon__c = cursistRecord.Cursist__c;
                facturatieRecord.Account__c = trainingRecord.factuur_bedrijf__c; 

                return facturatieRecord;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't set the `(SeeAllData=true)`. With this, you can't control the data tested. It depends on the data in your current org.

Comment: In addition to @MartinLezer comments, remove `seeAllData=true` and secondly, then you will not need to call `CreateInvoice` class.

Comment: Is in your CreateInvoice() Constructor you are doing Insert in for Loop? That might be Case

Comment: The error message says it... The limit exception is thrown in the CreateInvoice on the line 36. :-)

Comment: It appears you're creating too many records. Perhaps there are child records created during your test?

Comment: You are calling your main class `CreateInvoice` from your test class, with SeeAllData=true, and creating test data yourself. This is contradiction. Why are you calling `createinvoice()` then?

Comment: When i remove (SeeAllData=true) I only get coverage till line 20 from for(trainin__C I get no coverage

Comment: coverage issues relate to not mocking other objects needed by logic